# Powershell finally block not executed in windows task scheduler

Tags: powershell, scheduled-tasks, task-scheduler

I am running a windows task scheduler task:

```
Powershell 
-command C:\file.ps1  2>&1 > c:\test.log
```

`file.ps1` contains

```
Try{
    echo "a"
    sleep 5
    echo "b"
}
Finally{
    echo "c"
}
```

When I start the task manually and wait for it to finish, the test.log contains "abc". But when I interrupt it, by manually exiting it ("End" Button), it only contains "a".

I thought `Finally` is intented to even run when exiting a powershell script? My expected result was "ac"

Comment: It always depends on the kind of termination. Also note the mentioned about pipe handling on [about_Try_Catch_Finally](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_try_catch_finally?view=powershell-6&viewFallbackFrom=powershell-Microsoft.PowerShell.Core).

Comment: @Peter - if you forcibly kill a C++ program while executing in a try/finally, the finally also doesn't get executed.

Comment: Is it then somehow possible to execute something when a powershell script gets killed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As alluded to in the comments by Lieven Keersmaekers, the finally block doesn't get a chance to run when you use End to interrupt the task. This is because End just kills the process. PowerShell would be happy to run the finally block before doing its other exiting stuff, but PowerShell can't do anything at all after the process termination signal — it's dead. There is no way for any process to handle this. In the [words of Raymond Chen](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040722-00/?p=38373):

> TerminateProcess is the low-level process killing function. It bypasses DLL_PROCESS_DETACH and anything else in the process. Once you kill with TerminateProcess, no more user-mode code will run in that process. It's gone. Do not pass go. Do not collect $200.

There is a workaround, though. Since Task Scheduler's End command doesn't kill subprocesses of the task process, your main PowerShell script can kick off a watchdog process to perform any final cleanup. That script might look something like this (let's call it `watchdog.ps1`):

```
$watched = Get-Process -Id $args[0]
$watched.WaitForExit()
'Cleanup' >> c:\test.log
```

It takes a process ID, waits until that process exits, and only then does some cleanup, the equivalent of your finally block.

Then your main script might look like this:

```
$myPid = [System.Diagnostics.Process]::GetCurrentProcess().Id
$watchdog = Start-Process 'powershell' "-c .\watchdog.ps1 $myPid" -PassThru -WindowStyle Hidden
'Starting'
sleep 10
'Finished'
```

At the beginning, it starts the watchdog script, providing its own process ID. It then goes about its normal business, exiting normally once that's done.

If you want the watchdog's cleanup to happen *only* if the main script gets interrupted, add this line to the end of the main script:

```
$watchdog.Kill()
```

That will prevent the watchdog from proceeding beyond its second line.

Your redirection will only apply to the main process, so the watchdog has to handle its own output direction. Depending on your scheduled task's configuration, you might need to put the full path to the watchdog script in the watchdog-launching command of the main script.